# Process multiple XML files in the same folder and save them using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to extract the contents of `soap:Body` from multiple XML files in a folder. It is working for a single file as the following:

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
doc.LoadXml(doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("soap:Body", mgr).ChildNodes[0].OuterXml);
doc.Save(@"E:\new.xml");
```

To do the same for multiple files, I am using the following code:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
string path = @"C:\Folder";
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{
    xDoc.Load(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), file));
    XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
    mgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    xDoc.LoadXml(xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("soap:Body", mgr).ChildNodes[0].OuterXml);

}
```

How to save the files after processing them?

Comment: Well what part of saving the file are you stuck on? It's not really clear what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
string path = @"C:\Folder";
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{
   xDoc.Load(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), file));
   XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
   mgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
   xDoc.LoadXml(xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("soap:Body", mgr).ChildNodes[0].OuterXml);
   doc.Save("E:\\" + file);
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you TaiT's. But when I try to use `doc.Save("E:\\" + file);` I get an exception (The given path's format is not supported)

Comment: That's because your "file" variable contains the absolute path and not just the file name. That's what return the [EnumerateFiles function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx). Meaning your "file" variable starts with "C:\.." and it's trying to save the files like this : "E:\C:\Your\Path.xml" which obviously is not a well formated path and is source of error. Try doing so : ` doc.Save("E:\\" + Path.GetFileName(file))`. This will save the file in your E:\ root with the same filename. And please don't forget to mark it as answer if it's working for you cheers.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think I understand what you asking about.

You are looping over every document in some kind of folder, and then you want to save every file after some edits to another folder ?

You can add some variable as counter in foreach loop, and use Save() method as such(so that each file is saved with new name):

```
doc.Save(string.Format(@"E:\new{0}.xml", counter);
++counter; // new number for next file
```

Or you could use TaiT's answer and save each file with same name as original.